# Get number of non-empty elements from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have ten arrays with empty value

```
onTable[0 to 10];
```

look

```
["Jean5", "Jean3", "Paul2", "Jean6", "", "Paul4", "Jean", "peirre4", ""]
["Paul5", "peirre6", "peirre3", "", "Jean4", "Paul", "peirre5", "Jean2", ""]
...
```

I want get length of each array without empty value and without create ten variables for check that.

I have test this solution
[count empty values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265940/count-empty-values-in-array) but i dont want make ten variable. ie: `count1, count2,...`.

I check too [compare two arrays based on length: skip empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413223/compare-two-arrays-based-on-length-skip-empty-values) but is not what i want.

If possible, I want this look like

```
onTable[0].length(exclude(""))
```

What is the good way for make that?

Comment: Use filter() and remove empty value then get its length

Comment: i dont want remove value from array

Comment: filter will not update the existing array.... it's just return the new array

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `filter` with `Boolean` to filter non-empty elements from sub-array and use `length` on it.

```
onTable[0].filter(Boolean).length
```

As empty string is falsy in JavaScript, it'll be removed from filtered array.

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [
  ["Jean5", "Jean3", "Paul2", "Jean6", "", "Paul4", "Jean", "peirre4", ""],
  ["Paul5", "peirre6", "peirre3", "", "Jean4", "Paul", "peirre5", "Jean2", ""]
];

var len = arr[1].filter(Boolean).length;
document.write(len);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function for your need: check value to `undefined` or `null` etc.

```js
var arr = [
  ["Jean5", "Jean3", "Paul2", "Jean6", "", "Paul4", "Jean", "peirre4", ""],
  ["Paul5", "peirre6", "peirre3", "", "Jean4", "Paul", "peirre5", "Jean2", ""]
];

var len = arr[1].filter(function(x){ return x != ""}).length;
document.write(len);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `prototype`:

```js
Array.prototype.lengthWihtoutEmptyValues = function () {
    var initialLength = this.length;
    var finalLength = initialLength;

    for (var i = 0; i < initialLength; i++) {
        if (this[i] == "") {
            finalLength--;
        }
    }

    return finalLength;
}

var arrays = [
  ["Jean5", "Jean3", "Paul2", "Jean6", "", "Paul4", "Jean", "peirre4", ""],
  ["Paul5", "peirre6", "peirre3", "", "Jean4", "Paul", "peirre5", "Jean2", ""]
];

var arrayLength = arrays[0].lengthWihtoutEmptyValues();

$("#arrayLength").html(arrayLength);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrayLength"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid "wasting" memory and inducing excessive GC. You can [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) each sub array to a count of it's non-empty values:

```
sub.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return prev + (!!cur);
}, 0);
```

In order to process the entire master array, you can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to lengths:

```js
var arr = [
  ["Jean5", "Jean3", "Paul2", "Jean6", "", "Paul4", "Jean", "peirre4", ""],
  ["Paul5", "peirre6", "peirre3", "", "Jean4", "Paul", "peirre5", "Jean2", ""],
  ["Just1", "", ""]
];

var lengths = arr.map(function(sub) {
  return sub.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + (!!cur);
  }, 0);
});
document.write('[' + lengths.join('], [') + ']');
```